# Unreal C++ / GetActorOfClass

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I’m fairly new to Unreal C++ and I have a bit of trouble finding how to correctly write a GetActorOfClass (singular, not GetAllActorsOfClass) in C++ in order to set a reference to another AActor at BeginPlay.

I have included GameplayStatics in the include in the header and cpp of AActor A and also the AActorB.h .

Now, what I did in the first place is simply in the AActor A header file, declare a UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere,BlueprintReadWrite) AActorB*ActorB so that I can set the AActor B manually in the editor but I would prefer to set it with a GetActorOfClass in the begin play of AActor A.

What would be the correct syntax for that ?

Thanks

Edit : This is the BP version of what I try to do in C++ :

[BP Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRHaZ.png)

Edit 2 : What I tried in C++

```
   void ALocalMaster::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    GameManager = static AActor*GetActorOfClass(const UObject*GameManager,TSubclassOf<AGameManager>);
}
```

Comment: Please include a minimal code example of what you have tried.

Comment: I've added a picture of the BP version of what I try to do in C++

Comment: Types and modifers like `static` and `const` are used in declarations, not invokations. This is basic C (and C++), not Unreal-specific.

Comment: The pasted code indicates that you are also new to C++, you should start by learning the language, at least the basics. Also, what is this: `AActorB*ActorB`? Are `AActorB` and `ActorB` variables or classes?

Comment: They're actor variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, just use `GetAllActorOfClass` and dynamic cast it to your actor subtype if necessary:

```
// be sure to use #include "Containers/Array.h" 
// as well as #include "Kismet/GameplayStatics.h"

// Assuming GameManager is of type AMyGameManagerActor*

void ALocalMaster::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    AActor* FoundActor = UGameplayStatics::GetActorOfClass(GetWorld(), 
            AMyGameManagerActor::StaticClass());

    GameManager = Cast<AMyGameManagerActor>(FoundActor);
 
    if(GameManager == nullptr)
    {
        // handle error
    }
    else
    {
        // do stuff with GameManager
    }
}
```